# How to set the constraints(Min/Max) of a TimePicker [SAPUI5]

Tags: javascript, sapui5

i wonder wether or not it's possible to set the constraints of a `TimePicker`, that it should only display/allow to select the time between 12:00 - 17:00.

**Attempt**:

for an Input there are possibility to set certain constraints:

```
 <Input value="{path: 'modelExample&gt;/example', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.String' , constraints:{ minLength:20, maxLength:70 }}" />
```

Question: Is it possible to set constraints for a TimePicker ?

Answer (score 0):

Something along those lines (may need fixing, wrote it out of my head):

Note the type [Time](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.84.13/#/api/sap.ui.model.type.Time) (uses same constraints as Date)

```
<Input 
    value="{
        path: 'modelExample>/example',
        type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Time',
        formatOptions: { format: 'HH:mm' }, // may need pattern aswell, not sure anymore
        constraints: { minimum: '12:00', maxLength: '17:00' }}"
/>
```